# Is there a way to replace a customer email address in sql if it is not given

Tags: sql

How do i replace a customer email address with for example 'unknown@gmail.com' if the customer email address is not given in sql? I have tried using the replace sql code.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's generally considered a poor practice to use some 'special' value to indicate 'none' or 'unknown'.  What's wrong with just leaving the column as NULL?  In the end, that will be much easier to deal with, and much more logical than coding to say 'this email address really means there is no email address'.

Comment: NULL values make sense. Don't store "unknown" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run an update statement. Depending on what value is in the field where the email is you could run something like this :

```
Update customers
Set email = 'unknown@gmail.com'
where email is null or email = ''
```

To specify it down to a specific user, add their unique identifier as an and statement like this

```
Update customers
Set email = 'unknown@gmail.com'
where email is null or email = ''
and user_id = 123456
```

Comment: I think you want `=''` not `LIKE ''`.

Answer (score 0):

1. add default constraint to your column :

```
alter table
alter column_name set default 'unknown@gmail.com'
```

or

2. replace it if it is null whenever its needed ( in insert, update, etc...)

```
coalesce(email_col, 'unknown@gmail.com') , ....
```